# Unable to install VLC player

Tags: software-installation

Using Ubuntu 14.04.1LTS. While trying to install VLC, it's throwing this error: "Package dependencies cannot be resolved" - it seems some packages are missing in order to install VLC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a terminal prompt...

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Hey, can you please explain that the second command does?

Comment: It will force to get the dependencies for you.